# Performance tool on CodedUI Tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, performance-testing

Currently I am noticing my automated tests (CodedUI) are running a bit slow at times. I want to run a performance profiling tool on them as they run through VS2010. I have tried to use Red Gate's ANTs Profiler but am confused as to what process (or other?) I am supposed to attach it to.

The closest I came was by starting the Profiler from commandline and having a Mstest.exe call that runs a few tests as the process argument. This only returns me VS method performance and not my own test code.

```
//e.g
Profile.exe /e:"Mstest /testcontainer:Tests\bin\debug\CodedUITests.dll /test:Login /unique" /csv:"C:\testing\results.csv"
```

I constructed this command from [here](http://www.red-gate.com/supportcenter/content/ANTS_Performance_Profiler/help/7.4/APP_CommandLineWalkthrough) and [here](http://www.matthewbussa.com/2010/10/how-to-run-coded-ui-tests-from-command.html).

**Does anyone know a clean way to kick off a group of tests with a cpu/memory profiler (locally or otherwise) and then read the results?**

*Available machines in order of preference: Windows 7/XP/Server 2008 R2*
*Can run from: VS2010, or as part of a Build (TFS/Lab Management)*

Comment: I remember that process is called QTAgent.

Comment: @nikita Thanks, I did try hook on to the QTAgent32 process, but the results it returned were no closer to my code than Mstest unfortunately.

Comment: What kind of app you are running? WinForms or Web? If WinForms then attach to your winForms app, if web then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading into it further I found that I needed to **instrument my binaries** in order for the profiler to know about my methods at runtime. I did this using [VSInstr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182402.aspx) which will convert the test dll into an instrumented one. Then when I run the profiler with my above command line the profiler works.

i.e

- Run: `VSinstr.exe Your.Tests.dll`
- Open the ANTs Profiler.
- Select Mstest.exe as the .Net Executable.
- Set the test projects bin\Debug folder as the Working Directory.
- In the arguments place:
  `/testcontainer:C:\...\YOURTests\bin\debug\Your.Tests.dll /test:LoginTest`

Comment: FYI: In some instances, the Working Directory should be the root of your solution, not the bin, especially when dealing with assemblies containing relative path IO look-ups. +1 (and more if I could!) for the VSInstr information.

Answer (score 0):

If you're pretty confident your tests aren't going to blow up in some nasty way, you could also add `/noisolation` to the arguments you're passing to mstest. That is, your command would say,

`Profile.exe /e:"Mstest" /args:"/testcontainer:Tests\bin\debug\CodedUITests.dll /test:Login /unique /noisolation" /csv:"C:\testing\results.csv" /data:c:\testing\moodilymooh`

As another thought, you can add `/data` to the profile command to make it output an app[0-9]+results file that you can play with from the GUI.